# Are the following time complexity calculations correct?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

For each of the following, find the dominant term(s) having the sharpest increase in n and give the time complexity using Big-O notation. Consider that we always have n>m.
[image: my answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an error in the second and third expressions:

Assuming 2(n+1)<sup>3</sup>+nlogn<sup>5</sup> represents 2(n+1)<sup>3</sup>+nlog(n<sup>5</sup>), the dominant term is 2(n+1)<sup>3</sup>, which is O(n<sup>3</sup>). The second term is O(nlogn), since nlog(n<sup>5</sup>)==5nlogn.

In 2n<sup>2</sup>logn+5nlog<sup>2</sup>n, the first term is the dominant term, since it's O(n<sup>2</sup>logn) which grows faster than nlog<sup>2</sup>n, which is equal to n*logn*logn (since n grows much faster than logn).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :D